# Passing additional data through my JSON object,that is returned from the auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net MVC web application. I have the following action method, which will return Tag numbers as   JSON to be displayed as an autocomplete results, :-

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term){
    var ad = repository.FindServer(term, true).OrderBy(p => p.Technology.Tag).Select(a => new { label = a.Technology.Tag }).ToList();
    return Json(ad, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And my auto complete field is:

```
<text>Search</text>
<input  placeholder="Search by Tag.." name="searchTerm" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Rack")" type="text" class="searchmargin" />
```

But I want to be able to pass additional data such as the “Server Name  & Data created” in addition to the current tag number, to be part of the returned json.But to do the auto complete based on the tag number.

I am looking for something such as the auto complete result returned inside facebook . where if you type a name you will get the person networkinfo & Country,  so that you can know which person we want to .
Regards

**edit**
the action method is:-

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term){
    var tech = repository.AllFindTechnolog(term).ToList();
    var resources = repository.GetResources(tech.Select(a=>a.IT360ID.Value).ToArray(),false).ToList();
    var query = from techItems in tech
                join resourcesItems in resources
                on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID // join based on db2ID
                select new {  label = techItems.Tag, name=  resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME };

        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to get the sort of functionality you are after you are going to need to do it with JavaScript so that you can access the [`_renderItem`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) function.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('Rack/Autocomplete', function (data) {
        $('input[name="searchTerm"]').autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: data,
            create: function () {
                $(this).autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $('<li>').append('<a>' + item.label + '<br>' + item.name + '<br>' + item.label + '</a>')
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                };
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Can see it working in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sP9xn/3/).

For older versions of jQuery:

```
create: function () {
    $(this).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $('<li>').append('<a>' + item.label + '<br>' + item.name + '<br>' + item.label + '</a>')
                        .appendTo(ul);
    };
}
```

or even older:

```
create: function () {
    $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $('<li>').append('<a>' + item.label + '<br>' + item.name + '<br>' + item.label + '</a>')
                        .appendTo(ul);
    };
}
```

Comment: i tried the following  $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function (data) {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000 }).autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $('<li>').append(
                '<a>' +
                    item.label + '<br>' +
                    item.name + '<br>' +
                    item.label +
                '</a>').appendTo(ul);
        };
    });. but only the tag si being displyed

Comment: Have you changed `Select(a => new { label = a.Technology.Tag })` to add the new properties? e.g. `Select(a => new { label = a.Technology.Tag, name = a.ServerName, date = a.Date })` ?

Comment: yes i did this inside my action method,, please check my edit

Comment: and when i use the firebug i saw that the returned json have the correct combination of "Tag"+ "Name", but the auto complete result contained only tag

Comment: When you say autocomplete result are you talking about what is filled in the text box or the suggestion lines in the drop-down?

Comment: result is the suggestion lines,, sorry for not explaining it clearly .. btw i do not have a drop down list ,,, i have an input field ..

Comment: Could you possibly supply a sample of some of your JSON data?

Comment: here is a sample of the returned data using firebug. [{"label":"cab100385","name":"123"},{"label":"CAB100372","name":"1231"},{"label":"C100381","name":"asasdas"},{"label":"CAB100382","name":"werwerwerwe"},{"label":"CAB100383","name":"wwqeqweqw"},{"label":"C100385","name":"latest server500"},{"label":"C100395","name":"tdm server 501 602"},{"label":"CAB100399","name":"werwerwe"},{"label":"C100406","name":"12323123213232"}]

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint in the `_renderItem` function to ensure that the code is being run.  Could it be a caching issue?  Your JSON response looks like it should work fine as shown here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sP9xn/2/)

Comment: the _renderItem is working well as i try using static text and it was displayed well... and i cleared the cache also but nothing solve the issue. one thing is that i am using a web template from this link usman.it/free-responsive-admin-template/ but i do not think the problem is inside the templete

Comment: no errors ,, but i have noted something i manually add a static text as follow:-return $('<li>').append(
                '<a>' + 'statictext!!!!' + 
                    item.label + '<br>' + . but it was not displayed as part of the autocomplete result, seems there is something preventing my autocomplete from work as defined ,, and only the label is being displayed...

Comment: and if i remove the whole ".autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $('<li>').append(
                '<a>' +
                 '123' + item.name + '<br/>' +
                    item.customername + ' | ' + item.resourcename +
                '</a>').appendTo(ul);
        };" . part my autocomplete still works ..

Comment: It sounds like there is some other code, in the template maybe, that is overriding your autocomplete functionality.  Is there any other JavaScript on your page that is calling autocomplete?

Comment: no there should not be any other javascripts for autocomplete, and if i remove the whole autocomplete script ,, then the autocomplete will stop working.. which means there is not other scripts ,, is my assumption correct?

Comment: Sounds correct to me.  What version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: jQuery version is 1.8.2 & the UI is 1.8.24

Comment: i tried your code $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({
            source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000,

            create: function () {
                $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $('<li>').append('<a>' + item.label + '<br>' + item.name + '<br>' + item.label + '</a>')
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                };
            }
        });
    }); . but the autocomplete stop working.

Comment: What was the error? What about the `ui-autocomplete` one?

Comment: this worked for me  $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {